# DryIoC register configuration

Tags: xamarin, prism, dryioc

I am working on a Xamarin project with Prism and DryIoC.

Currently I am setting up some custom environment-specific configuration, however I am struggling with the IoC syntax for this.

I have the following code as part of my App.xaml.cs:

```
private void SetConfiguration(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            // Get and deserialize config.json file from Configuration folder.
            var embeddedResourceStream = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IConfiguration)).GetManifestResourceStream("MyVismaMobile.Configurations.Configuration.config.json");
            if (embeddedResourceStream == null)
                return;

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(embeddedResourceStream))
            {
                var jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var configuration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration.Configuration>(jsonString);

                What to do with configuration, in order to DI it?
            }
```

What should I do with the configuration variable to inject it?
I have tried the following:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IConfiguration, Configuration>(c => configuration);
containerRegistry.Register<IConfiguration, Configuration>(c => configuration));
```

But the syntax is wrong with dryIoC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterSingleton` and `Register` are meant for registering *types* where the container will then create the instances. You have your instance already, so you use

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>( configuration );
```

Instances are always singleton, obviously, so there's only no separate `RegisterInstanceSingleton`...

Comment: This makes so much sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be the same steps if I were to implement a custom HttpClient? In that case, I would like to set the BaseAddress when doing DI. I could be new'ing up a httpclient, and setting the baseaddress, and the adding it using registerInstance. However is it possible to give an argument like i'm used to: services.AddHttpClient<ICustomHttpClientService, CustomHttpClientService>(client =>
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(mleCoreBaseUrl);
                })

Comment: You can create an interface like `IClientFactory` with a `Create` method, I guess that's the easiest and clearest way.